# JSF ajax and websocket, sync data

Tags: ajax, jsf, websocket

For JSF webapp, how to use web socket to sync data between different web clients? For example, After User A places an order, User B should see it immediately. The order table is a list of rows(orders). Each row can have JSF components such command links. When a client receives websocket message, how to create the row for
the table? Client does not know how to render a JSF component such as command link if the order row contains JSF component.

```
  function onMessage(...)  {

  }
```

Another issue is that: after a row is added, it will not sync with its view on server side. For example, 5 rows on client, 4 rows on server side. Clicking a command link on the new row will not fire action event on the server side.

How to solve this two issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the websocket in turn fire an ajax request.

Below example assumes [OmniFaces `<o:socket>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket) which utilizes [`<o:commandScript>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript) for the hidden ajax action.

```
<h:panelGroup id="foo">
    ... (some complex UI here) ...
</h:panelGroup>

<h:form>
    <o:socket channel="someChannel" onmessage="commandScriptName" />
    <o:commandScript name="commandScriptName" action="#{bean.pushed}" render=":foo" />
</h:form>
```

The upcoming OmniFaces 2.6 will further improve this use case by enabling `<f:ajax>` support in `<o:socket>`.

```
<h:panelGroup id="foo">
    ... (some complex UI here) ...
</h:panelGroup>

<h:form>
    <o:socket channel="someChannel">
        <f:ajax event="somePushMessage" listener="#{bean.pushed}" render=":foo" />
    </o:socket>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks. JSF 2.3 websocket is very basic, does not provide this solution.

Comment: Dave, it will in next milestone (Mojarra 2.3.0-m07). I've personally taken care of that. As you probably already know, the <f:websocket> is namely largely based on <o:socket>.

Comment: great! wondering if it is possible to execute bound bean method on server side directly and then push ajax update to all listening clients. It will perform better than the current solution.

Comment: Sure it is. See "EJB design hints" section of <o:socket> documentation.